# I need help in complements of subsets

Tags: mathematical-optimization, education, mathematica-online, webmathematica, grid-mathematica

I have two subsets and tried this expression with `MapThread`:

```
TT := {{{P1}, {P2, P3}}}
XX := {P1, P2, P3, P4}

MapThread[Complement, {{Flatten[XX]}, {Flatten[TT]}}, 1]
```

> {{P4}}

I need the partial sets' complements so that the outcome would be `{{P2,P3,P4},{P1,P4}}`

Comment: Please add links to/from Wolfram Community cross-post. That way readers can see all prior responses and avoid duplication.

Answer (score 4):

You have too many braces in TTt. Note also, you should not use uppercase names, because these are used by the system.

Here is working code:

```
t = {{P1}, {P2, P3}};
 x = {P1, P2, P3, P4};
Complement[x, #] & /@ t

{{P2, P3, P4}, {P1, P4}}
```

Answer (score 4):

We could also use `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
a = {{P1}, {P2, P3}};
b = {P1, P2, P3, P4};

DeleteElements[b, #] & /@ a
```

{P2, P3, P4}, {P1, P4, P1}}

Unlike `Complement`, `DeleteElements` doesn't sort its output

```
a = {{P3}, {P2, P1}};
b = {P4, P3, P2, P1};

DeleteElements[b, #] & /@ a
```

{{P4, P2, P1}, {P4, P3}}

```
Complement[b, #] & /@ a
```

{{P1, P2, P4}, {P3, P4}}

Unlike `Complement`, `DeleteElements` doesn't automatically delete duplicates. Therefore we must apply `DeleteDuplicates` to `b`

```
a = {{P3}, {P2, P1}};
b = {P4, P3, P2, P1, P1};

DeleteElements[DeleteDuplicates @ b, #] & /@ a
```

{{P4, P2, P1}, {P4, P3}}

It should also be noted, that `DeleteElements` is much slower than `Complement`. But it is useful if we have short lists and want to preserve the original sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to preserve the original order is to use `DeleteCases` and `Alternatives` as follows:

```
a = {{P3}, {P2, P1}};
b = {P4, P3, P2, P1};

DeleteCases[b, Alternatives @@ #] & /@ a

(*{{P4, P2, P1}, {P4, P3}}*)
```